# Accessing restAPI response outside function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to be access array outside the function or outside the loop in nodejs. I written following code.

```
var result = [];
 function setid (swfid){
crud.getswift(swfid).then(function (response) {
    console.log("response",response);
    result = response;
    // res.send(response);
}).catch(function (err) {
    return ("error:" + err);
});
console.log("result",result);
}
console.log("result",result);
```

But its returning null. your suggestions please

Answer (score 2):

You wrote a new statement in the function call and therefore you scoped it. This is one of the things wrong there. Apart from that, as the first person commenting to this answer mentioned, you have an async call here. Therefore, you need to return a promise from `setid` and wait for the response to get the result.

Comment: Nope. The call is asynchronous, you are going to display empty result both time

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT shame on me, I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: But then, it's kind of weird because he doesn't need to wrap the `crud.getswift` with another promise since it's a promise. There is something missing in the question in my opinion.

Comment: `crud.getswift.` am getting response but  `setSeid()` also getting response. when I console the response like `console.log("response",response);`  when i trying to assign into one variable its return null

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing your Aysnc logic with Sync. You won't get the response outside the .then function scope because there's no response available at the time you're trying to get the results.

Try using a callback in the promise - You'd need to invoke the function in the promise callback and send the response as function param, then play with the data.

```
> Promise / API call etc
.then(() => gotDataCallBack(data));

 gotDataCallBack(data){
 // handle your data and logic here.
 // this will make sure you have the data available before you move ahead with 
 your application/manipulation logic.
}
```